# RSA and exponent not relatively prime with Euler Phi

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I would like to know which drawbacks are there if the public exponent (e) is not coprime with the Euler phi (phi(N)) in RSA. That is to say GCD(e, phi(n)) != 1.

As far as I know the drawback is that in this way we are not sure that there exists a d such that e*d = 1 mod phi. Are there any other drawbacks?

Comment: You'd probably do better asking this on [security.se] or [cryptography.se] but check their help centres before you post.

Answer (score 3):

A modular multiplicative inverse of `a mod n` exists if and only if `gcd(a, n)= 1`. So, yes, they must be coprime.

Generally, just use 65537 as your public key exponent. There are no advantages for choosing a random e, and 65537 is sufficient large to protect against [Coppersmith's Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_Attack) and has some qualities that make it particularly efficient for square and multiply algorithms to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a example: `N=65` and `e=3`.

Then, if we encrypt the plaintext `2`, we get `2^3 mod 65 = 8`

However, if we encrypt the plaintext `57`, we get `57^3 mod 65 = 8`

Hence, if we get the ciphertext `8`, we have no way of determining whether that corresponds to the plaintext `2` or `57` (or `32`, for that matter); all three plaintexts would convert into that one ciphertext value.

Making sure `e` and `ϕ(N)` are relatively prime ensures this doesn't happen.